# pushwoosh-cordova-plugin Unable to receive push message on android when the app is not in the foreground or background

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, pushwoosh

I have similar problem as the issue link below

https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-phonegap-plugin/issues/60

Any idea how to solve this problem? Do I have to manually configure something in the AndroidManifest.xml or android.json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the below plugin

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push

and follow the below link to complete the procedure to complete the process of push notifications.

https://devdactic.com/ionic-push-notifications-guide/

this will give you complete idea to implement push notifications.

Comment: no please use the phonegap-plugin-push code it will work don't use pushwoosh

Comment: okay then... i need to confirm with my superior on this matter then since we are using pushwoosh at this moment...